# Is there a way of writing subscript in one's answer (or question)?

Tags: support, formatting

Is there a way to write subscript on EL&U?

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

**Yes**.  Use the **`<sub>…</sub>`** tags.

For example:

> In the series ***x***<sub>1</sub>, **x**<sub>2</sub>, **x**<sub>3</sub>, ⋯ **x**<sub>n</sub>, we see …

There are corresponding **`<sup>…</sup>`** tags.

And for certain, specialized uses, there are specific Unicode characters you might find useful¹.

¹ <sub>Such as the superscript numerals</sub>

### More Formatting Options

I have yet to find one source that completely describes all the markdown and HTML features StackExchange supports, but these four together seem to cover the bases:

1. [Editing help](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help): list of all the standard Markdown features available in "plain text" editing.
2. [Canonical Markdown reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) (external): note that SE's Markdown may deviate from this spec in order to tailor the syntax for its own purposes.
3. [HTML tags supported by SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites): These are HTML tags, over-and-above the formatting features offered by Markdown, which SE supports. The `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags mentioned above fall into this category.
4. [Magic links supported in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000): These are handy shortcuts for use in comments which make it easier to say common things, like "*questions about the site belong on [Meta]*", which will automagically convert the bracketed text to a link to that specific stack's meta.

Then there are small details like [```-style Markdown code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-markdown-code-blocks), which I'm not sure are comprehensively collected anywhere.  If anyone does know of a single, central, consolidated, comprehensive, and authoritative reference, add a comment and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Although you can't use HTML in titles or comments, which makes writing your ***x₁, x₂, x₃, ··· xₙ*** a lot harder here — if even possible at at all.